# How do I make an front-end HTTP proxy to perform app maintenance without downtime?

Tags: reverse-proxy, apache-2.4

We have a web application in Java (although the language is not really relevant for this question), and it is frontend by Apache via a simple proxy.

Is there a way to queue all the HTTP requests from the clients (so that their HTTP connection is maintained and not dropped) while we shutdown the Java Application Server (or any other container...) with our app. The maintenance takes <60 seconds, so the idea is that we just deploy a new version of application and then say "allow traffic back to the web application again", so that customers will experience a delay but not a drop of connections - as the queued requests will not be allowed to reach our app.

To be more clear, we are not dealing here with a website, but actually these are API requests done over HTTP, and the clients are actually using code libraries which support the specified delay - so the clients will know to wait (while we are doing the maintenance).

Do you have any ideas? If needed, we can develop a small app for this if there is no obvious/off-the-shelf solution, although this is a very common problem experienced basically by anyone providing an HTTP API to their clients.

Comment: You don't specify much about the proxy set-up.  is it mod_proxy acting as a reverse proxy?  I take it cached results to API calls would not do?  Is the proxy accessing the Java backend on a different server?  Via localhost?

Comment: hi, yes it is a reverse proxy, and cache would not work. The important thing is that when someone requests a HTTP endpoint that the requests is put on a queue somewhere, and that the application "workers" are emptying the queue and returning the result (using the same mechanism in reverse). Thus the web server shouldn't directly need to know about the (number or location of) clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following kind of principle?  Say it's mod_proxy, ensure ProxyTimeout and the ProxyPass connectiontimeout= (and probably retry=) is at least the maintenance time or the API client idle timeout.

Then, before the maintenance, firewall all new connections on the backend, eg `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 8080 -j DROP`.  After the maintenance, remove the rule with `iptables -D`.

MaxClients could possibly stay low, but you might want to increase `ListenBackLog` if the TCP connection timeout in the client is short.

Comment: Is there a web server which submits HTTP requests into a messaging queue, so that it can be handled by the pool of workers?

Comment: You initially the client "HTTP connection is maintained and not dropped" which does imply a proxy like Varnish or Apache.  In which case how many requests are likely to be made over the minute of outage?  If you use the Worker mpm, you could accept and queue thousands of requests; if the client can wait for the server to answer use ListenBackLog. 

On the other hand, if the HTTP request can be completed and the results returned by some asynchronous callback or something, then some bit of PHP to store and forward the POST data might work.  Does it need to be a strict FIFO queue?

Comment: "Does it need to be a strict FIFO queue" - no, any worker can reply to the message in the queue, it doesn't have to be in serial order.

Answer (score 0):

Simply start the new version of the application in it's own instance (i.e. on a different port) and update the reverse proxy configuration to redirect requests to the new instance, which can be done without down-time. (`apachectl reload`)

Then take down the old version and instance freeing up the resources.

Comment: And what if I have to change the database schema? I mean, if I update one app instance (and run it on a new port, update proxy config etc.) the old one which is still running will break because it is now not compatible with the new schema.

Comment: Then such an approach doesn't work with the same database! Or it still might, depending on the quality of your SQL statements and the changes you're trying to make, i.e. a new table not being referenced by the older version can happily be created. Some more info [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)

Comment: I was thinking of making a small app which (theoretically) never changes, and which terminates the HTTP towards the client (and after the reverse proxy), which will then put the incoming requests into a queue. Then my real business app would just process this queue. And if there are no workers (e.g. the maintenance is in progress) then the messages in the queue would just wait until there is one. In that case I can change the db schema as much as I want, since nothing is being processed at the moment, it is only stored in the queue.